# What is the meaning of "objectively better" in this sentence

Tags: puns

I read a sentence in Word by Word by Kory Stamper which was:

> If you ask a modern adherent to this rule why, exactly, you aren't supposed to end a sentence with a preposition, they merely goggle at you as if you had just asked why you aren't supposed to lick electrical sockets. Because it is *objectively better* not to, that's why.

The fact that the "objectively better" part is italicised as well as answer both the above mentioned questions makes me think that the author is making a pun here. Regarding the latter question, I think the word "objective" means "based on experience and facts" and regarding the former question, I think it somewhat relates to the "objective case" we learn in grammar.  But I am still not sure. Am I right?

Comment: *Objectively* is used in contrast to *subjectively*, so if you say that something is *objectively better* it means that this is not just your opinion but that anybody who knew the facts would have to agree it was better. Here the author is being sarcastic - he is saying that people who adhere to this rule can't give a coherent reason for it and end up saying *that's just the way it is*.

Comment: Consider that "that's why" is an optional phrase and can be omitted.  Then what does the sentence end with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it is a pun - I think Minty's comment covers what's happening : when asked "why" people have resorted to a response that's effectively "just because", which is likely to be infuriating and suggests that they're not really able to come up with an answer. The italics are to emphasis a change in tone, which I agree would probably be sarcastic.

The rule is not to end a sentence with a preposition, but if doing that improves clarity, provides brevity or takes consideration of the audience, the question "why shouldn't I do that?" doesn't have a satisfactory answer. This leaves people who want to argue that the rule is sacrosanct with an answer no better than "because we said so".

There might also be a pun there, but if there is I'm not sure what it's on about.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is this. An object normally comes after a preposition. Therefore the pun is **where do you put the object if the preposition is at the end**. "Because it is **objective**ly better not to"

Explanation. A preposition can be understood as anywhere a dog can be in relation to its doghouse. A dog can be: in the doghouse around the doghouse near the doghouse on the doghouse. All of these preposition examples show where the dog is in relation to its doghouse (The **Object**)

Comment: But then, how does "objectively better" answers the second question?